# Center within a border applied to element using css `after`

Tags: css, flexbox

I'd like to create a bordered element with text appended to the element using `after`. The text needs to be centered within the border, to appear like a button. Currently the text sits on the bottom. I tried using a [flex webkit](http://learnlayout.com/flexbox.html), but it only horizontally centers the text.

[image]

```
#wrapper {
  background-image: none;
  border:1px solid #021a40 !important;
  left: 0px !important;
  top: 115px !important;
  &:after {
    content: 'Some Text';
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display:         flex;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
```

If I add padding to the `after`, where the text is, it expands the border out... and doesn't put the text in the center of the border:

`padding-bottom: 15px;`

[image]

How can I center the text in the middle of the border?

---

Also, If I try centering using `margin-left/right: auto`, it places the text at the bottom left:

```
  &:after {
    content: 'Some Text';
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Is the parent element a fixed height? Is the string always a fixed length?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `display: table` property.

However, this will not work if you have `position: absolute`. Suppose you need to use that, you must wrap your `#wrapper` in another wrapper and put the positioning attributes there.

```
#wrapper {
  display: table;
  background-image: none;
  border:1px solid #021a40 !important;
  left: 0px !important;  <--- you need to declare `position` for these to work
  top: 115px !important;   <--- you need to declare `position` for these to work
  &:after {
    content: 'Some Text';
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
#wrapper {
  background-image: none;
  border:1px solid #021a40 !important; 
  position:relative; /*add this*/
  &:after {
    content: 'Some Text';
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
  }
```